# Still have a TransactionAbortedException after the transactionScope.Compete() is called

Tags: c#, transactions

Get a transactionAbortedException at the end of using (transactionScope) block. The transactionScope.Complete() is called ,why I still get this exception.

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, CreateTransactionOption(10)))
{
    // Distributed actions about databases.
    status = SafeAction(realAction).Status;
    scope.Complete();
    return status;
}
```

the innerException is:

```
SqlException: Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MS DTC) has stopped this transaction.
```

Comment: Are you using a distributed transaction?

Comment: Yes. but the clients and servers are in the same machine. When I am developing.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve].